# Problems with MacOS command shell after installing Dropbox upgrade

Tags: python, path, zsh, dropbox, macos-monterey

Recently I installed a Dropbox update on a Mac M1 mini (Monterey) which changed the Dropbox folder from a simple folder to a "Location" in the Finder. I found the new path name, which is
in my home directory under Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox.

I was reminded that it's possible to drag an object from the Finder into the Terminal app, but only if you use the whole pathname. If you try to 'cd' down one directory at a time, you get a permission error when the working directory is Dropbox.

```
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini / % cd /Users
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini /Users % cd joecascio 
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini ~ % cd Library 
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini Library % cd CloudStorage 
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini CloudStorage % cd Dropbox 
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini Dropbox % ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini Dropbox % pwd            
/Users/joecascio/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox
```

But if you just skip over trying to cd through the Dropbox folder, it works.

```
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini Dropbox % cd /
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini / % cd Users/joecascio/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/projects/COVID-19
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini COVID-19 % ls
CLL-COVID-action-plan       ct-towns
COVID-19_Town_Level_Data.csv    ct.numbers
Stonington.numbers      new-london-ct.numbers
covid-19-data-master        state-county-bustout.py
ct-town-bustout copy.py     state-county-recent-bustout.py
ct-town-bustout-old.py      states
ct-town-bustout.py
```

It's probably something to do with permissions, but I can't figure what because the permissions on the Dropbox folder are as follows.

```
joecascio@Josephs-Mac-mini CloudStorage % sudo ls -la              
total 24
drwxr-xr-x    4 joecascio  staff   128 Jan 22 20:47 .
drwx------@ 102 joecascio  staff  3264 Jun  2  2022 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 joecascio  staff  8196 Jan 24 14:22 .DS_Store
drwx------@  66 joecascio  staff  2112 Jan 24 06:02 Dropbox
```

Any ideas would be welcome, esp from Dropbox support.

Comment: _that refer to linux pathnames don't work anymore_ : Can you add to your question an example, in what way they don't work anymore?

Comment: See revisted problem statement above.

Comment: Did you check your effective user-id? If this is not the culprit, I would crosspost this question at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), because AFIK, Apple has extended the simple security model provided by BSD Unix, and people at _AskDifferent_ may know better about it. Don't forget to place a crossposting note in both postings, if you decide to cross-post.

Comment: effective uid and id are the same. I wonder if becoming the super-user would work.

Comment: Likely it would, but I would first research the specifics of the permission systems on a Mac, as I recommended in my last comment. Of course, the Dropbox support should also be able to help, since the problem occurs after you installed the Dropbox update.

Answer (score -1):

You can drag path from finder to terminal.

[Drag path to iTerm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kea3u.gif)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).